# Using .xinitrc, some apps take a long time to open

Tags: xinit

I'm using ~/.xinitrc (and startx) to start my window manager. It works just fine but some apps are taking a long time to open (i.e. thunar, nemo, etc). Can someone offer some advice on how to track the problem down?

~/.xinitrc:

```
 #!/bin/sh

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources &
exec berry
```

Thanks. I'm on Ubuntu 21.04. Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: You mentioned file managers. Are there other apps having the same problem? If not then it's unlikely to be related with the way the window manager is being started but probably the delay has to do with some mount point point.

Comment: `nemo` is part of a desktop environment itself; so your running it will cause a fair amount of the GNOME/Cinnamon desktop backend to be loaded before `nemo` can appear available for use. Light file-managers exist that aren't tied to desktops, so why have you chosen heavy ones linked to desktops you appear to not want to run ?  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/nemo).   *this may not be your "long" time but long is a little vague*

Comment: It does seem to be happening with certain apps and not others. File managers like thunar, nemo, and nautilus are taking between 10 and 20 seconds to start. So is Sublime-Text (although I did open a file from the file manager …). Google-chrome opens fine, as do most other apps (like terminals).

Comment: And why would graphical file managers and other apps be having this problem at all? It wasn't happening when I logged in using GDM :/